C# HttpClient MultipartFormDataContent send integer values
I have been testing this API and can only get it working when I use this RestClient. This RestClient wants to install about 20 other packages into my project so I would like to get it working with the HttpClient. I believe this error comes from the two integers status and priority and help would be great.
GitHub
https://github.com/freshworks/fresh-samples/blob/master/C-Sharp/CreateTicketWithAttachment.cs
Working:
var options = new RestClientOptions(_freshdeskUrl)
{
    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(apiKey, "X")
};
var client = new RestClient(options);

var request = new RestRequest("", Method.Post);

request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.AddParameter("email", "tom@outerspace.com");
request.AddParameter("subject", "panel can't see files");
request.AddParameter("description", "confirm whether received");
request.AddParameter("name", "Name");
request.AddParameter("status", "2");
request.AddParameter("priority", "1");

var response = client.Execute(request);

Console.WriteLine(response);

Not working:
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
string authInfo = apiKey + ":X";
var byteArray = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(authInfo);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
form.Add(new StringContent("panel can't see files"), "username");
form.Add(new StringContent("tom@outerspace.com"), "email");
form.Add(new StringContent("confirm whether received"), "description");
form.Add(new StringContent("2"), "status");
form.Add(new StringContent("1"), "priority");

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(_freshdeskUrl, form);

//response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
httpClient.Dispose();

Error Returned from server
StatusCode: 201, ReasonPhrase: 'Created', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Wed, 09 Oct 2024 14:05:36 GMT
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  Status: 201 Created
  Cache-Control: no-store
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
  X-Freshservice-Api-Version: latest=v2; requested=v2
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-Request-ID: b27d2c81-78c7-96af-8f5e-5c24fbecc271
  Location: https://nccnusersupport.freshservice.com/api/v2/tickets/21027178338
  X-Envoy-Upstream-Service-Time: 321
  X-Fw-Ratelimiting-Managed: true
  X-Ratelimit-Total: 140
  X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 139
  X-Ratelimit-Used-Currentrequest: 1
  X-Trace-Id: 00-da1535c2223299d7d3040faac49b8719-e0b5e2503d7f2fb5-01
  Nel: { "report_to": "nel-endpoint-freshservice", "max_age": 2592000, "include_subdomains": true}
  Report-To: { "group": "nel-endpoint-freshservice", "max_age": 2592000, "include_subdomains": true, "endpoints": [{"url": "https://edge-admin.us-east-1.freshedge.net/nelreports/freshservice"}]}
  Server: fwe
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: Wed, 13 Oct 2010 00:00:00 UTC
}}


Is there a specific response status code or body you're receiving that indicates there's an error in the Not Working case?

You're lying (to the server) with the Content-Type in your RestSharp request. The content RestSharp is sending is consistent with a content type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, not multipart/form-data. In C# you're actually sending a multipart/form-data request (with content that corresponds to it), so it's not working.

OP: Can you come back with what the server actually expects in terms of the request content?

I included a GitHub link that the vendor has

http response 201 is an error?

Using the vendor's sample code, we get a request that looks like this:
POST https://www.example.com HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------8dce90e5ec77e04
Content-Length: 7355

------------------------------8dce90e5ec77e04
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

example@example.com
------------------------------8dce90e5ec77e04
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

Ticket Title
------------------------------8dce90e5ec77e04
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

Ticket description.
------------------------------8dce90e5ec77e04
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="status"

2
------------------------------8dce90e5ec77e04
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="priority"

2
------------------------------8dce90e5ec77e04
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachments[]"; filename="x.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

FileContentHere
------------------------------8dce90e5ec77e04--

So we can match that using MultipartFormDataContent:
var data = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    { new StringContent("example@example.com"), "email" },
    { new StringContent("Ticket Title"), "subject" },
    { new StringContent("Ticket description."), "description" },
    { new StringContent("2"), "status" },
    { new StringContent("2"), "priority" }
};

// You can use any Stream here (e.g. FileStream)
using Stream file = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("FileContentHere"));
data.Add(new StreamContent(file)
{
    Headers = { ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain") }
}, "attachments[]", "x.txt");

await client.PostAsync(_Url, data);

This code now produces the following request:
POST https://www.example.com HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="41a104f2-a8b3-4da0-935b-98610ec8580d"
Content-Length: 930

--41a104f2-a8b3-4da0-935b-98610ec8580d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=email

example@example.com
--41a104f2-a8b3-4da0-935b-98610ec8580d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=subject

Ticket Title
--41a104f2-a8b3-4da0-935b-98610ec8580d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=description

Ticket description.
--41a104f2-a8b3-4da0-935b-98610ec8580d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=status

2
--41a104f2-a8b3-4da0-935b-98610ec8580d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=priority

2
--41a104f2-a8b3-4da0-935b-98610ec8580d
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachments[]"; filename=x.txt; filename*=utf-8''x.txt

FileContentHere
--41a104f2-a8b3-4da0-935b-98610ec8580d--

This now closely matches the vendor's sample request, and should work. FYI I got the request data by using Telerik's Fiddler (the Classic version).
